# Decide rather a text is about "Topic A" or not - NLP with Python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, word2vec

I'm trying to write a python program that will decide if a given post is about the topic of volunteering. My data-sets are small (only the posts, which are examined 1 by 1) so approaches like LDA do not yield results.

My end goal is a simple True/False, a post is about the topic or not.

I'm trying this approach:

1. Using Google's word2vec model, I'm creating a "cluster" of words that are similar to the word: "volunteer".

```
    CLUSTER = [x[0] for x in MODEL.most_similar_cosmul("volunteer", topn=120)]
```

2. Getting the posts and translating them to English, using Google translate.
3. Cleaning the translated posts using NLTK (removing stopwords, punctuation, and lemmatize the post)
4. Making a BOW out of the translated, clean post.
5. This stage is difficult for me. I want to calculate a "distance" / "similarity" / something that will help me get the True/False answer that I'm looking for, but I can't think of a good way to do that.

Thank you for your suggestions and help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to intuitively improvise a set of steps that, in the end, will classify these posts into the two categories, "volunteering" and "not-volunteering".

You should looks for online examples that do "text classification" that are similar to your task, work through them (with their original demo data) for understanding, then adapt them incrementally to work with your data instead.

At some point, word2vec might be a helpful contributor to your task - but I wouldn't start with it. Similarly, eliminating stop-words, performing lemmatization, etc might eventually be helpful, but need not be important up front.

You'll typically want to start by acquiring (by hand-labeling if necessary) a training set of text for which you know the "volunteering" or "not-volunteering" value (known labels).

Then, create some feature-vectors for the texts – A simple starting approach that offers a quick baseline for later improvements is a "bag of words" representation.

Then, feed those representations, with the known-labels, to some existing classification algorithm. The popular `scikit-learn` package in Python offers many. That is: you don't yet need to be worrying about choosing ways to calculate a "distance" / "similarity" / something that will guide your own ad hoc classifier. Just feed the labeled data into one (or many) existing classifiers, and check how well they're doing. Many will be using various kinds of similarity/distance calculations internally - but that's automatic and explicit from choosing & configuring the algorithm.

Finally, when you have something working start-to-finish, no matter how modest in results, then try alternate ways of preprocessing text (stop-word-removal, lemmatization, etc), featurizing text, and alternate classifiers/algorithm paramterizations - to compare results, and thus discover what works well given **your** specific data, goals, and practical constraints.

The `scikit-learn` ["Working With Text Data" guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html) is worth reviewing & working-through, and their ["Choosing the right estimator" map](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/machine_learning_map/index.html) is useful for understanding the broad terrain of alternate techniques and major algorithms, and when different ones apply to your task.

Also, `scikit-learn` contributors/educators like Jake Vanderplas ([github.com/jakevdp](https://github.com/jakevdp)) and Olivier Grisel ([github.com/ogrisel](https://github.com/ogrisel)) have many online notebooks/tutorials/archived-video-presentations which step through all the basics, often including text-classification problems much like yours.

Comment: Thank you for that informative answer. I will start going through scikit-learn and the git repos that you provided. I have a question, the feature vector can be similar to the "cluster" that I created if I understood you correctly?

Comment: Only some of the potential classifiers you could easily try, once you have the basic pipeline in place, will literally calculate a new candidate text-vector's summary-value 'similarity' to some 'cluster'. (And, those may not be the best-performing classifiers!) So don't over-focus on that approach, even though it is intuitively attractive. Instead, several of the available classifiers will essentially  learn specialized domain-specific comparators, far more powerful/beneficially-weighted than the raw vector-similarities you'd naively calculate between your input text vectors.

Comment: My biggest problem is that I can't acquire large datasets. I can't find good data to work with and hand labeling thousands to sets will take too much time. I started with a cluster and a BOW as a beta version of my "filter" because I have no data to work with. After running my first filter, I will hopefully acquire data, might not be too reliable, but data non the less. After hand labeling said data, I will start looking at text classification but now I just can't do that.

Comment: It's always a challenge but any classification effort is highly dependent on the number of "ground truth" labeled examples that can be collected. Many of the classifiers can output not just a class, but a confidence. So, once you've got a baseline – which may just be a handful of hand-labeled strong-examples – you can direct extra labeling attention to the "difficult"/low-confidence examples. And once you can deploy an initial/test system to a larger audience, you may be able to get them to label/correct errors, rapidly increasing the effective training data.